# Why it is needed $ = jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dollar-sign

Question is nearly theoretical. But last time I've encountred some subtle bug. When the page contains child frame and both parent and child frame are used the same js file, if I not set $ = jQuery on the start, functionality of this js file crashed. What the trick could be here?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean, but `$ = jQuery` is set internally already.

Comment: Maybe you are using an extremely old version of jQuery or the script is built weirdly. Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: Ok! Thanks all! I've caught my fault, problem is in jQuery.noConflict()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there are other JavaScript libraries included anywhere in the page, they might use `$`. [Mootools](http://mootools.net/) and [Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/) both use `$`.

If you include jQuery and then you include Prototype then the `$` variable will be over-written, so you'd have to set `$ = jQuery` before any jQuery code would work:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jQuery.js" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="prototype.js" />
<script>$ = jQuery</script>
```

Equally, as @Guffa says, if you called [noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) anywhere it would unset the `$` variable.

Ideally, I don't think you should use the `$` variable, as it can cause problems. Just do something like:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
var jQ = jQuery;
```

And then use the `jQ` variable as you would have the `$`. Then you won't get conflicts.

Answer (score 3):

That should not be needed unless you removed the reference from the `$` variable.

Check if you are using the [noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) method somewhere to decouple jQuery from the `$` variable, or have something else (like a function) named `$`.